# Payum Paypal Rest config_path

Tags: symfony, paypal-rest-sdk, symfony-3.1, payum, paypal-plus

I am trying to implement paypal-rest payment with the payum bundle in symfony (3.1.4).
I need to get PayPal Plus running in my Symfony App.
Therefore I read this article
https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/paypal/rest/get-it-started.md

Now - I can't figure out what the 'config_path' parameter is ment to be set to and what exactly has to be provides at this config_path.

Symfony states

```
'The config_path fields are required.'
```

My payum config looks like this atm

```
payum:
    security:
        token_storage:
            AppBundle\Entity\PaymentToken: { doctrine: orm }

    storages:
        AppBundle\Entity\Payment: { doctrine: orm }

    gateways:
        paypal_express_payment:
            factory: paypal_express_checkout
            username:  "%ppe_uname%"
            password:  "%ppe_pw%"
            signature: "%ppe_signature%"
            sandbox: false
        paypal_rest_payment:
            factory: paypal_rest
            client_id:      "%ppr_cid%"
            client_secret:  "%ppr_sec%"
            sandbox: true
```

The paypal_express_payment part works fine.

If I add just a random config-path like 'my_config.txt' Symfony states

```
Request GetHumanStatus{model: ArrayObject} is not supported. Make sure the gateway supports the requests and there is an action which supports this request (The method returns true). There may be a bug, so look for a related issue on the issue tracker.
```

So - where and what is the config_path ment to be?

Any help or hints for more documentation that can lead into the right direction is very welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's meant to be [sdk_config.ini](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/sdk_config.ini) from PayPal-PHP-SDK

```
gateways:
    paypal_rest:
        factory: paypal_rest
        client_id:  '%paypal_rest.client_id%'
        client_secret:  '%paypal_rest.client_secret%'
        config_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/config/sdk_config.ini'
```

UPDATE: I don't think that Doctrine ORM storage is supported by Payum PaypalRest plugin.
[PaypalRest\Action\CaptureAction](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/src/Payum/Paypal/Rest/Model/PaymentDetails.php) requires the model (Payment) to be inherited from PayPal\Api\Payment and then it uses its create and execute methods for payment capture. I don't think it's a good idea to extend from PayPal\Api\Payment in the Doctrine entity.

I was able to eliminate this error by using [Payum\Paypal\Rest\Model\PaymentDetails](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/src/Payum/Paypal/Rest/Action/CaptureAction.php) as a payment and filesystem as a storage:

```
payum:
    storages:
        Payum\Paypal\Rest\Model\PaymentDetails:
            filesystem:
                storage_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/payments
                id_property: idStorage
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks very sensible. However I then still get this error: `Request GetHumanStatus{model: ArrayObject} is not supported. Make sure the gateway supports the requests and there is an action which supports this request (The method returns true). There may be a bug, so look for a related issue on the issue tracker.` @karser

Comment: Any hint on how to use the class "PaymentDetails" from paypal-rest payum in my config.yml to specify the storage? It seems this part is missing...

Comment: @user3440145 Indeed, documentation is missing. I made some progress on it and eliminated the error. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I now can proceed with the implementation. About the same problem was described here: https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle/issues/363 However I didn't manage to figure it out until your answere here. Thx!

Comment: I'm trying the same but still run into the `Request GetStatus{model: ArrayObject} is not supported. Make sure the gateway supports the requests and there is an action which supports this request (The method returns true). There may be a bug, so look for a related issue on the issue tracker.` error on: `ExecuteSameRequestWithPaymentDetailsAction.php`

Comment: @karser also the config_path need to point to a directory when looking at:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/ff2a7f9c2ddc47a22cb7bb8a5b0bb97bd16bdd6f/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalConfigManager.php#L37
so `config_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/config // folder incloding sdk_config.ini` would be correct

Answer (score 0):

Try to set it to default value like this:

```
paypal_rest_payment:
    factory: paypal_rest
    client_id:      "%ppr_cid%"
    client_secret:  "%ppr_sec%"
    sandbox: true
    config_path: ~
```