# Paypal REST payment gateway on Sylius

Tags: php, symfony, paypal, sylius, payum

I'm trying to implement Paypal REST payment method on sylius and I got the following error:
`Request GetStatus{model: ArrayObject} is not supported. Make sure the gateway supports the requests and there is an action which supports this request (The method returns true). There may be a bug, so look for a related issue on the issue tracker.`

With some researches I find out that's because the storage for paypal rest payment is misconfigured (cf [Payum Paypal Rest config_path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075507/payum-paypal-rest-config-path) accepted response).

So I tried to modify the config of the gateway as shown in the following code:

`payum:
    storages:
        Payum\Paypal\Rest\Model\PaymentDetails:
            filesystem:
                storage_dir: '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/payments'
                id_property: idStorage
    gateways:
        paypal_rest:
            factory: paypal_rest
            client_id: foo
            client_secret: bar
            config_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/config/sdk_config.ini'
            sandbox: true`

Nothing change, I still get the same error.

So in the Paypal Rest GetStatus request I tried to dump the request to know why it is not supported. The request must be an instance of GetStatusInterface (it's my case) and `$request->getModel()` must be an instance of Payment but I have an ArrayObject instead. Here is the full dump of the model:
`#model: ArrayObject {#4410 ▼
    #input: null
    flag::STD_PROP_LIST: false
    flag::ARRAY_AS_PROPS: false
    iteratorClass: "ArrayIterator"
    storage: []
  }`

I guess that my storage is not right configured because it is empty but I don't understand why because I did it in my config.yml file.

Hope someone has a solution ;)

Comment: Can you give a stacktrace of `Request GetStatus{model: ArrayObject} is not supported` error please? IMO it depends in which class was created an GetStatus object